# Only show one drop down item at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to modify the jquery so that I can only open one list item at a time and would only like to modify the existing version of my code

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".contacts ul li").on("click", function() {
      if ($(this).find("ul").css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).find("ul").show();
        $(this, ".contacts ul li").addClass("selected")
      } else {
        $(this).find("ul").hide();
        $(this, ".contacts ul li").removeClass("selected")
      }

    });
  });
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro', Sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.contacts {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: solid 1px #111;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-top: 51px;
}

.contacts h1 {
  font-size: 1.250em;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #131313;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#3e3e3e+0,252525+100 */
  background: #3e3e3e;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #252525 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #252525 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3e3e 0%, #252525 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3e3e3e', endColorstr='#252525', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  z-index: 9999;
}

.contacts ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.contacts ul li {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #565656;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contacts ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #212121;
}

.contacts ul li ul {
  margin: -15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.contacts ul li ul li {
  background-color: #444 !important;
  cursor: default;
  color: #999 !important;
}

.contacts ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.avatar {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 32px;
  -moz-border-radius: 32px;
  border: solid 3px limegreen;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #484848 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.status {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.offline {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.away {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

.mail {
  color: #00f6ff !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .contacts {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="contacts">
    <h1>Contacts</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="status"></div>Christian
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">christian@yahoo.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status offline"></div>Rich
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">rich@hotmail.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status away"></div>Dave
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">dave@tripod.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status"></div>Frank
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">frank@live.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status"></div>James
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">james@aol.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status"></div>Eddie
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">eddie@outlook.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post your code at 3rd party sites. It's harder for us to quickly answer you and those 3rd party links can become broken over time, making your question meaningless here.

Comment: Understood. This makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".contacts ul li").on("click", function() {
    $('.contacts ul li').removeClass('selected').children("ul").hide();
    $(this, ".contacts ul li").addClass("selected").children("ul").show();
  });
});
```

***Working example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".contacts ul li").on("click", function() {
    $('.contacts ul li').removeClass('selected').children("ul").hide();
    $(this, ".contacts ul li").addClass("selected").children("ul").show();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro', Sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.contacts {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: solid 1px #111;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-top: 51px;
}

.contacts h1 {
  font-size: 1.250em;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #131313;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#3e3e3e+0,252525+100 */
  background: #3e3e3e;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #252525 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e3e3e 0%, #252525 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3e3e 0%, #252525 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3e3e3e', endColorstr='#252525', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  z-index: 9999;
}

.contacts ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.contacts ul li {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #565656;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contacts ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #212121;
}

.contacts ul li ul {
  margin: -15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.contacts ul li ul li {
  background-color: #444 !important;
  cursor: default;
  color: #999 !important;
}

.contacts ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.avatar {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 32px;
  -moz-border-radius: 32px;
  border: solid 3px limegreen;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #484848 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.status {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.offline {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.away {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

.mail {
  color: #00f6ff !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .contacts {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="contacts">
    <h1>Contacts</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="status"></div>Christian
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">christian@yahoo.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status offline"></div>Rich
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">rich@hotmail.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status away"></div>Dave
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">dave@tripod.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status"></div>Frank
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">frank@live.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status"></div>James
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">james@aol.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="status"></div>Eddie
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Phone</strong>: 555.555.555</li>
          <li><strong>Email</strong>: <span class="mail">eddie@outlook.com</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JakeDuncan  glad to help you.:):)

Comment: Is there a way to make the item clicked closable again too using this method? Once it's opened, it can only be closed at the moment by clicking another item, and not itself, if that makes sense?

Comment: @JakeDuncan  we can do that with some improvement. But it will be more good to ask a new question , so that it will be answered. Changing  a answer time-to-time based  on new requirement is not very good idea.

Comment: Could you help me achieve this? It would overall, complete this question, otherwise there would be 2 questions to achieve 1 overall objective :)